# Add another code to webpage when the link is index.php?action=feed&type=member

Tags: php, html, forms

Simply I want another code to be added to the webpage when the url is

```
index.php?action=feed&type=member
```

for example the code that is on the page when the url is index.php?action=feed  is

```
<form method="post" name="contactform" class="form" id="form1" action="l.php">

  <p class="name">
    <input name="first_name" type="text" placeholder="Name" id="name" />
  </p>

  <p class="email">
    <input name="email" type="text" id="email" placeholder="Email" />
  </p>

  <p class="text">
    <textarea name="comments" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
  </p>


  <div class="submit">
    <input type="submit" value="SEND" id="button-blue"/>
    <div class="ease"></div>
  </div>
</form>
```

and the code I want to be added when the url is index.php?action=feed&type=member is

```
<form method="post" name="contactform" class="form" id="form1" action="l.php">

  <p class="name">
    <input name="first_name" type="text" placeholder="Name" id="name" />
  </p>

  <p class="email">
    <input name="email" type="text" id="email" placeholder="Email" />
  </p>

  <p class="text">
    <textarea name="comments" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
  </p>

  <p class="username">
    <input name="user" type="text" id="user" placeholder="Username" />
  </p>

  <div class="submit">
    <input type="submit" value="SEND" id="button-blue"/>
    <div class="ease"></div>
  </div>
</form>
```

I know that it may be easy , but I am a beginner . so how can this be done in PHP ? 
Sorry for my English . 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want such output, you could put an `if` statement along the html form. Consider this example:

url: `index.php?action=feed&type=member`

```
<form method="post" name="contactform" class="form" id="form1" action="l.php">
    <p class="name">
        <input name="first_name" type="text" placeholder="Name" id="name"/>
    </p>
    <p class="email">
        <input name="email" type="text" id="email" placeholder="Email"/>
    </p>
    <p class="text">
        <textarea name="comments" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
    </p>
    <?php if(isset($_GET['type']) && $_GET['type'] == 'member'): ?>
    <p class="username">
        <input name="user" type="text" id="user" placeholder="Username"/>
    </p>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <div class="submit">
        <input type="submit" value="SEND" id="button-blue"/>
        <div class="ease">
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

That particular markup should appear is those conditions are met.

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($_GET["type"] == 'member') {
 echo '<p class="username">
 <input name="user" type="text" id="user" placeholder="Username" />
 </p>';
}
```